# Updating a child id inside a child id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase data created as follows

```
ParentDetail
-LMqLua-spvoXALIkhSw
 -LNiOVHSfPol9YgrvegD
  parentAge: 32
  parentFamily: 4
  parentHeight: 156
  parentWeight: 72

-LMqLvEerswoFSzjM9FE
 -LNiOlA2Ea2ierv_XXgK
  parentAge: 38
  parentFamily: 4
  parentHeight: 158
  parentWeight: 48
```

How do i get the first child id so i can update the database, i get the second child from intent in previous activity.
So far here is my code.

```
mDatabase.child("child").child(how_to_get_this_id).child(userId).setValue(ParentDetail);
```

Comment: So you say that `LNiOVHSfPol9YgrvegD` and `LNiOlA2Ea2ierv_XXgK` are user ids? Are you sure are not pushed keys?

Comment: Yes, those are pushed keys @AlexMamo

Comment: So `.child(userId)` is basically `.child(LNiOVHSfPol9YgrvegD)`, right?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get that child value

```
    mDatabase.child("child").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot  = dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
               String requiredId = snapshot.getKey();
               //Now  here call your method
               mDatabase.child("child").child(requiredId).child(userId).setValue(ParentDetail);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: `DataSnapshot snapshot  = dataSnapshot.getChildren()` that looks like it won't compile.

Comment: why @FrankvanPuffelen ?

Comment: DataSnapshot snapshot = (DataSnapshot) dataSnapshot.getChildren(); it gives an error

Comment: Because `DataSnapshot.getChildren()` returns an `Iterable<DataSnapshot>` and not a `DataSnapshot`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getChildren()

Comment: Thank you. Is that Okay now ?

Comment: It works, but it's also adding a same data inside -LMqLvEerswoFSzjM9FE @AliAhmed

Comment: @BonifasiusEdwin hav you tried this code without for Loop?